# How to set window size and position in trimesh

Tags: python, window, trimesh

I have trimesh 3.9.32 installed on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) armv7l. This snippet:

```
import trimesh

mesh = trimesh.creation.cylinder(1, height=1)
mesh.show()
```

displays a window spilling into my second display. I would like to control window size and position. I tried to use `trimesh.viewer.SceneViewer`, but I'm getting `AttributeError: module 'trimesh' has no attribute 'viewer'`. What is a way to set window size and position or make it full screen on my primary display?

Answer (score 1):

The following should fix your problem:

```
from trimesh import viewer
from trimesh.viewer import windowed
```

Source: https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/issues/427

Comment: Thanks, that solves syntax problem and `trimesh.viewer.SceneViewer(scene, resolution=(800,800))` works as expected. Any clue about window position or full screen mode?